# htaccess to Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've converted apache htaccess rules to nginx rewrite rules but they are not working for me.

Apache .htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/layout/themes/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bootstrap/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) bootstrap/$1 [L]
```

Nginx rules:

```
location /public/layout/themes/ {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/public/layout/themes/(.*)$ /public/layout/themes/bootstrap/$1 break;
  }
}
```

Can anyone please check what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you use online tool to convert your apache rules to nginx. This is may not be the correct way.  I think, [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/) reference is useful for you.